# Ratio Test of Limits

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Using the fact that if $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{s_{n+1}}{s_n}=L<1$ then $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}s_n = 0$

Show that:

$$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\frac{2^n}{n!} = 0$$

Workings:

$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\frac{2^n}{n!} = 0$

Show that

$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\frac{2^{n+1}}{(n+1)!} < 1$

Now I am stuck. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Since $s_n$ is $\frac{2^n}{n!}$, you should find $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{2^{n+1}}{n+1!} / \frac{2^n}{n!}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $a_n = \frac{2^n}{n!}$. Then

$$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} = \frac{n!}{2^n}\cdot \frac{2^{n+1}}{(n+1)!} = \frac{2}{n+1}$$

Show that the limit of $a_{n+1}/a_n$ is $0$.

Comment: Oh yeah. I messed that up. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: You're not using the hint. The hint is to calculate the limit of $s_{n+1}/s_n$, where $s_n = 2^n/n!$.

Answer (score 1):

You need to consider the limit $s_{n+1}/s_n = 2/(n+1)$.